# Noob question on Validation Summary control

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, validation

I think this problem is probably a simple solution.

Im trying to use Validation Summary control, when i run the page and enter invalid input i get the error summmary (fine) but when i try to rectify the error by entering correct info the page wont run and the summary stays (even though the Validation Control message goes.)

Thanks

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexStns" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txtStones" 
        ErrorMessage="Weight (Stns) Must be one or two number characters." 
        ValidationExpression="/d/d?"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txtPounds" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
        ValidationExpression="\d\d?"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
    <br />
```

Comment: Actually it seems to be getting hung up on the first REGEX Validator

Comment: Why use `\d\d?` instead of `\d+`?

Comment: Because im doing stones and pounds and i only want 1 or 2 digits in each box. Think ill try reoplacing the dodgy regex validator, filing that the text box :(

Comment: Ok, fixed it...it was that stupid 0 i had in the text box!!!

Comment: The first validator has "/d/d" instead of "\d\d" ... might that be your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the normal behavior of the ValidationSummary control.

Comment: If thats the case doesn't the user end up staring at an unusable page if he makes a mistake??

Comment: Why is the page unusable? The errors are fixed, and the user can still re-submit. But the summary of why they couldn't submit the first time remains so they can see that it didn't go through the first time. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, i probably didn't put the question very well. The validation summary was holding the page even when i thought i had re-entered valid input. I had a default 0 in the texbox cause i was messing aroung with jscript validation yesterday (to no avail) :)

Comment: Ah, in that case it sounds like not so much an issue with the ValidationSummary control, as it is with the other validators on the page. Think of the ValidationSummary control as display only. It is the other validators that cause the page to not submit. (At least, that is how it is supposed to work!)